# Bone rotating in IK despite axis lock

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics, bone.constraints

I have an ik chain of 2 bones. I have it set so that the first bone has a y axis lock but the second bone has an x and z axis lock. In spite of this, when using the ik, the first bone still rotates in its y axis. Anyone know how to properly lock the axis for the first bone?
[image: Y axis lock on bone with problem]

[image: First Bone rotating in y axis despite axis lock]

Comment: Another bone is required to define the angle between the bones. Try to create a parent bone for 'Bone'.

Comment: I tried that and I still have the same problem